# Will spider plants buried under heavy clay garden soil survive?

Tags: houseplants

I put several spider plant babies in my apartment's backyard around the beginning of September, when the leaves were about 2 inches long. I mixed perlite and pumice into the soil, put a paper bag over it, and covered that with a mixture of potting soil, perlite, pumice and garden soil. Then I put the babies in with the roots in potting soil wrapped in paper towel to give them more time to grow. They were in a corner of the yard that got filtered or dappled light from about 11-3, and I watered them once or twice a week.

Toward the end of September, the maintenance guy shoveled a bunch of soil on top of them, claiming he thought they were weeds (even though you could see paper towel poking through around each of them). The soil is heavy clay and it has broken glass and rusty nails mixed into it so I don't want to touch it.

I can see one of the babies that wasn't fully covered up still has green on the edges of the leaves but it's literally only 1.5 inches that shows through. The others were completely covered.

Has anyone had any spider plants covered up like this come back to life?

Comment: How about a picture and your location?

Comment: You don't say how long they were buried. A week? Okay. 10 weeks? Dead. Dig them up with a rake and see. Whether we say dead or alive, you still have to dig and see. Gloves for roses will not be pierced by glass.